# Transfer physical Windows Server 2008R2 licence to Hyper-V server

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I have a plan to upgrade my 2008R2 Standard Edition to 2012R2 Standard Edition, and then virtualize them with Hyper-V 2012R2. Is it possible to upgrade from Windows Server 2008R2 Standard Edition to Windows Server 2012R2 Standard edition if I have SA (software insurance)?
What would be my next steps for legal OS licensing for this environment? Can I use these licenses for virualizing environment (Hyper-V server)? 
I have seen that with SA you can migrate from 2008R2 Standard to 2012R2 standard, but I couldn't figure out can I transfer these licenses to new server?
I read a lot about licensing rights, but I couldn't find the exact situation that would be of use for me.

Answer (score -1):

Software assurance give you the right to upgrade during software assurance life .

You don't have to transfer license but request new one. Its in your microsoft vlsc account.

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/

be carefull with virtual licensing . microsoft say : 2012 r2 is 2 vitual + 1 physical

references : http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=15477

Comment: Be careful with blanket answers to general questions. Microsoft Software-Assurance comes in many different forms and packages. For example, step-up licensing (mentioned in the question above) is not a guaranteed right with all versions of SA. As for the second point, I'm not entirely sure I follow, are you saying he should be careful because he has more licenses than he thinks (for the same price)?

Comment: Yep its why i link to the software assurance website . When you talk about virtualize and windows standard you don't have to forget the rule about ms licensing because virtual is not physical licensing. And its why i post the link . But i don't have 20 year to explain my answer so i resume idea so he can read understand and request answer on dark point .

Comment: We don't answer licensing questions here and you may be giving the OP licensing advice that isn't legally or technically correct, which is why we don't answer licensing questions here. The OP should contact Microsoft directly or contact a Microsoft licensing specialist.